# Object has no attribute 'split()' Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, split

Having an error where i'm trying to get the first work from a string that is passed in to a method within a class. But i am getting AttributeError: 'Deck' object has no attribute 'split' when I run. The 'new_card' that is passed in will be for example 'Two of Hearts'. and new_Card is a string and self.values is a dictionary

```
# returns integer value of a card
def get_card_value(self, new_card):
    return self.values[new_card.split()[0]]
```

and the error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/andypaling/Documents/Programming/python/random/card_game/game.py", line 146, in 
    if not Game.check_same_cards(player1_deck, player2_card):
  File "/home/andypaling/Documents/Programming/python/random/card_game/game.py", line 87, in check_same_cards
    if card1.get_card_value(card1) == card2.get_card_value(card2):
  File "/home/andypaling/Documents/Programming/python/random/card_game/game.py", line 40, in get_card_value
    split_string = new_card.split(' ')

thanks for any help

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and a `traceback`. It seems like `new_card` is not a string type.

Comment: Sorry, have done that

Comment: The code you provided is not sufficient to understand where the problem comes from. new_card does not seems to be a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey it seems like you are using a diffrent data type and not a string in your case judging that your making a card game i am guessing you are using a tuple. Try converting the data to a string then split it using the .split() function.

I hope this can help.

Comment: WOW! Thanks so much this saved my life, now I can meet my deadline for the project at my job. what a live saver